# Problem with turning Postal Dude while using Postal Plus keyboard controls

Tags: pc, postal

I just started playing Postal Plus, a 2001 enhanced edition of a 1997 original, on PC Windows XP. It's a very interesting game, but I have certain problem while playing using keyboard controls. Namely, turning left does not seem to work properly, as it only make Postal Dude turn slightly per each key press and does not turn at all while the button is hold. When pressing button for turning right, everything works fine (holding the key turns the Dude all the time). This problem does not seem to appear when using mouse controls (moving mouse left or right).

Is this how the game is meant to be played using keyboard controls?

Just note I never played or owned the original Postal, so I do not know if its the same.

Thanks!